# Tar running log file unix

Tags: unix, zip, tar

I have a huge log file. I know I can tar it at end but I want the file to get zipped after every 10K line and also ensure that no data is lost.

The final goal is stop the increasing size of the file and keep it at specific limit.

Just a sample code :--

```
sh script.sh > log1.log &
```

Now, I want keep zipping log1.log so that it never crosses specific size limit.

Regards,
Abhay

Comment: Ensuring that there's no data loss could be very difficult (depends on how frequently the file is written to) unless you have some cooperation within script.sh.

Answer (score 1):

let file be file.txt, then you can do :-

```
x=$(wc -l file.txt|cut -f 1 -d " ")
if [[ $x >> 10000 ]]
then
sed '1,10000d' file.txt > file2.txt
fi
```

After that just zip file2.txt and remove file2.txt

Comment: So, this need to be kept in while loop of parent script right ?

Comment: No need... you can run it separately from cron.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the **split** command. It can split by lines, bytes, pattern, etc.

```
split -l 10000 log1.log `date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-"`
```

This will split the file named "log1.log" into one or more files. Each file will contain no more than 10,000 lines. These files will be named something like 20180327-085711-aa, 20180327-085711-ab, etc. You can use split's -a argument for really large log files so that it will use more than two characters in the file suffix.

The tricky part is that your shell script is still writing to the file. After the contents are split, the log must be truncated. Note that there is a small time slice between splitting the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost.

This example splits into 50,000 line files:

```
$ wc log.text
  528193 1237600 10371201 log.text
$ split -l 50000 log.text `date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-"` && cat /dev/null > log.text
$ ls
20180327-090530-aa      20180327-090530-ae      20180327-090530-ai
20180327-090530-ab      20180327-090530-af      20180327-090530-aj
20180327-090530-ac      20180327-090530-ag      20180327-090530-ak
20180327-090530-ad      20180327-090530-ah      log.text
$ wc 20180327-090530-aa
   50000  117220  982777 20180327-090530-aa
```

If you only want to truncate the file if it reaches a certain size (number of lines), wrap this split command in a shell script that gets run periodically (such as through cron). Here's an example of checking file size:

```
if (( `wc -l < log.text` > 1000000 ))
then
    echo time to truncate
fi
```

Comment: This will split the final file . I want to split the running log file .